# Bootstrap responsive layout does not work properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap 2.2 I've got the following problem:

When I narrow my firefox window with the responsive layout, the nav-bar disappears and I am getting a button in the right corner instead. But clicking on that button does not do anything (normally, the menu should pop out).

I copied this HTML:

http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/example-responsive-design-with-twitter-bootstrap.html

and I replaced the CSS and JS imports by the following:

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

which are the standard .css and js files which one gets when downloading Bootstrap. The CSS and the bootstrap.js are loaded properly.

The bootstrap.js does contain the collapse section (I've pasted that part below)

Has anyone got any idea, why clicking on the button after collapse does not have any effect?

I am using firefox 18.0.2, the responsive layout works when opening other sites.

Thanks a lot

Collapse section of bootstrap.js:

```
/* =============================================================
 * bootstrap-collapse.js v2.2.2
 * http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse
 * =============================================================
 * Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 * ============================================================ */


!function ($) {

  "use strict"; // jshint ;_;


 /* COLLAPSE PUBLIC CLASS DEFINITION
  * ================================ */

  var Collapse = function (element, options) {
    this.$element = $(element)
    this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.collapse.defaults, options)

    if (this.options.parent) {
      this.$parent = $(this.options.parent)
    }

    this.options.toggle && this.toggle()
  }

  Collapse.prototype = {

    constructor: Collapse

  , dimension: function () {
      var hasWidth = this.$element.hasClass('width')
      return hasWidth ? 'width' : 'height'
    }

  , show: function () {
      var dimension
        , scroll
        , actives
        , hasData

      if (this.transitioning) return

      dimension = this.dimension()
      scroll = $.camelCase(['scroll', dimension].join('-'))
      actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.find('> .accordion-group > .in')

      if (actives && actives.length) {
        hasData = actives.data('collapse')
        if (hasData && hasData.transitioning) return
        actives.collapse('hide')
        hasData || actives.data('collapse', null)
      }

      this.$element[dimension](0)
      this.transition('addClass', $.Event('show'), 'shown')
      $.support.transition && this.$element[dimension](this.$element[0][scroll])
    }

  , hide: function () {
      var dimension
      if (this.transitioning) return
      dimension = this.dimension()
      this.reset(this.$element[dimension]())
      this.transition('removeClass', $.Event('hide'), 'hidden')
      this.$element[dimension](0)
    }

  , reset: function (size) {
      var dimension = this.dimension()

      this.$element
        .removeClass('collapse')
        [dimension](size || 'auto')
        [0].offsetWidth

      this.$element[size !== null ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('collapse')

      return this
    }

  , transition: function (method, startEvent, completeEvent) {
      var that = this
        , complete = function () {
            if (startEvent.type == 'show') that.reset()
            that.transitioning = 0
            that.$element.trigger(completeEvent)
          }

      this.$element.trigger(startEvent)

      if (startEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

      this.transitioning = 1

      this.$element[method]('in')

      $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('collapse') ?
        this.$element.one($.support.transition.end, complete) :
        complete()
    }

  , toggle: function () {
      this[this.$element.hasClass('in') ? 'hide' : 'show']()
    }

  }


 /* COLLAPSE PLUGIN DEFINITION
  * ========================== */

  var old = $.fn.collapse

  $.fn.collapse = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data('collapse')
        , options = typeof option == 'object' && option
      if (!data) $this.data('collapse', (data = new Collapse(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    })
  }

  $.fn.collapse.defaults = {
    toggle: true
  }

  $.fn.collapse.Constructor = Collapse


 /* COLLAPSE NO CONFLICT
  * ==================== */

  $.fn.collapse.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.collapse = old
    return this
  }


 /* COLLAPSE DATA-API
  * ================= */

  $(document).on('click.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this), href
      , target = $this.attr('data-target')
        || e.preventDefault()
        || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '') //strip for ie7
      , option = $(target).data('collapse') ? 'toggle' : $this.data()
    $this[$(target).hasClass('in') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('collapsed')
    $(target).collapse(option)
  })
```

`

Comment: Are you aware that bootstrap has updated to 2.3.0 ? Please upgrade

Comment: Thanks, I updated it, but still got the same problem

Comment: can ya check the solution . let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a responsive menu in bootstrap the following way : JSfiddle with nav [Navigation bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/DJtsa/)
Note : You have not included the jquery file into your html page, use the following way :

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
   <i class="icon-bar"></i>
  </a>

<a class="brand" href="">New Icon Menu</a>

    <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li><a href=""><i class="icon-home icon-2x"></i> Home<br></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href=""><i class=" icon-pencil icon-2x"></i>About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href=""><i class=" icon-briefcase icon-2x"></i>Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href=""><i class=" icon-envelope icon-2x"></i>Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That long bunch of inclusions let me overlook jquery.
I' m wondering why bootstrap guys don't include jquery directly in bootstrap.js...

Comment: Thats because its maintained seperately not by the twitter guys and it will complicate things that way . Use the cdn version for bootstrap css , js and even jquery . It will help you gain good response time .